# Cmake add_library ALIAS

Tags: cmake

I am trying to figure out exactly what [this](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/CMakeLists.txt#L48) line is for in the  cmake file of this github json project,

```
add_library(${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} ALIAS ${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME})
```

Specifically with this example, what does this allow in this cmake file that otherwise would not be possible?

I see no other references to `${PROJECT_NAME}::${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME}` in this CMakeLists.cmake, so I am confused as to what exactly this achieves.

Edit:

The key thing that this achieves, that the comment did not make obvious to me, is that it makes the targets work with the namespaces when the project is used through add_subdirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow using `nlohmann/json` project by adding it into your super project with add_subdirectory(...)

For example simple project structure:

```
<root project>\
     \thirdparty\json    <<-- git submodule to https://github.com/nlohmann/json
     \include\
     \src\
     CMakeLists.txt
```

In your project CMakeLists.txt

```
...
project(mySuperApp)

set(mySuperApp_SRC src/main.c)

# can under some conditions...
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/json)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${mySuperApp_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without the alias, you can still add the library via `add_subdirectory` however in the `target_link_libraries` command you would need to omit the namespace:

```
project(mySuperApp)

set(mySuperApp_SRC src/main.c)

add_subdirectory(thirdparty/json)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${mySuperApp_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE nlohmann_json)
```

If you did that but then decided to use `find_package` to include the library (as opposed to `add_subdirectory`), you would need to change `target_link_libraries` to use the namespaced targets i.e.

```
project(mySuperApp)

set(mySuperApp_SRC src/main.c)

find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${mySuperApp_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

by adding the alias, the target_link_libraries using the namespaced version (i.e. `nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json`) will work in either case and not require a change if you later decide to switch from `find_package` to `add_subdirectory`).

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to add the library with `find_package` OR `add_subdirectory` using the same target name for both:

```
# creates nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)

if (nlohmann_json_NOT_FOUND)
    # creates nlohmann_json AND nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
    add_subdirectory(thirdparty/json)
endif()

add_executable(your_target_name ${your_target_sources})
target_link_libraries(your_target_name PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

Without the alias, you would need:

```
# creates nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)

if (NOT nlohmann_json_FOUND)
    # creates only nlohmann_json
    add_subdirectory(thirdparty/json)
endif()

add_executable(your_target_name ${your_target_sources})
if (nlohmann_json_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(your_target_name PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
else()
    target_link_libraries(your_target_name PRIVATE nlohmann_json)
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using git's blame function shows that line was added in this commit: [`33a2154`](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/commit/33a2154f8dbff1382d84d6e463e31a5ac9f3da18), which has the following comment attached:

> CMake convention is to use a project namespace, i.e. Foo::, for imported
>   targets.  When multiple targets are imported from a project, this looks
>   like Foo::Bar1 Foo::Bar2, etc.  This adds the nlohmann_json:: namespace to
>   the exported target names.
>
> This also allows the generated project config files to be used from the
>   build directory instead of just the install directory.

Comment: Thanks. although commenting out this line, and generating the build again, results in identical output for the generated config files.